# Nuxt.js ignore (Is there any way to ignore original tags)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

1. I am creating a web page using Nuxt.js. (Static file built with the
   nuxt generate command)
2. As a requirement,I need to write the original tag in the static file
   that I built.  The original tag is for displaying the data obtained
   on the server side. Writing an original tag in a vue file naturally
   gives an error.

For example, in the image below,
Is there a way to ignore original tags in the vue file?

***vue file(example)***

```
// disabled-next-line
{{^ server-side-display-data}}
<button> button </ button>
// disabled-next-line
{{/ server-side-display-data}}
```

***Build file(example)***

```
{{^ server-side-display-data}}
<button> button </ button>
{{/ server-side-display-data}}
```

Tried
It seemed possible to ignore certain "files" like below, but I haven't found a way to ignore certain "tags"

https://ja.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-ignore/

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was looking for a solution... you can try with this solution i've used.

in your `nuxt.config.js`

```
...
vue: {
  config: {
    ignoredElements: [string or regexp],
  },
},
...
```

see this [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements) for more details